# Django REST Framework One to Many related field data insert and filtering

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two model, `Person` and `Appointment`. A `Person` have many `Appointment`.

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Appointment(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='appointments')
    date = models.DateField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = 'date',

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

and my serializers.py file is:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from appointment.models import Person, Appointment


class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('date',)


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    appointments = AppointmentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'appointments',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        appointments_data = validated_data.pop('appointments')
        person = Person.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for appointment_data in appointments_data:
            Appointment.objects.create(person=person, **appointment_data)
        return person
```

and finally my viewsets is:

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['name', 'appointments']
```

This return persons_list as my expectation:

```
    [
 {
        "name": "Arif Hasan",
        "email": "arif@gmail.com",
        "appointments": [
            {
                "date": "2016-10-10"
            },
            {
                "date": "2016-10-17"
            },
            {
                "date": "2016-11-07"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Atanu Shome",
        "email": "atanu@gmail.com",
        "appointments": [
            {
                "date": "2016-11-13"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

- But i can't create new appointment here.
- Can't filter person by date range.

Answer (score 0):

You should use tuples for specifying filter_backends, filter_fields. 
Also you want to filter by date field so you have to specify `appointments__date` in your filter_fields insted of just `appointments`.

You should have your viewset defined as follows:

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('name', 'appointments__date',)
```

Check : [Django filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend)

Comment: Filter is working though there is some problem, can you please help me But How can I create new appointment here.

Comment: what error you are getting . Also you said cant filter by date and now you say its working. please specify exact errors.

Comment: As one person have many appointment date, so when I filter by certain date  it return the person with all of its date.

Comment: Ok so if you pass date as ex. 2-nov-2016 it will return all persons who has appointment date as 2-nov-2016 right? I think this is correct behaviour. Also update your question with error traceback that you are getting while you create an appointment. My question is:  Why you are creating appointment at the time of creating person ? Shouldn't there be different endpoint for appointment creation?